# Why int& a=10; is valid in ancient C++ compilers?

Tags: c++, reference, turbo-c++, borland-c++

I was just wondering why ancient compilers like Turbo c++ 3.0(Blue screen IDE) & Borland Turbo C++ 4.5 etc doesn't report any error in following program.

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main()
{
  int& a=10;
  cout<<a;
  return 0;
}
```

The above program won't be accepted by modern C++ compilers, But why then ancient compilers allows this? They simply shows single warning in above program.

Comment: what warning do they show? and what error does an up to date compiler show?

Comment: @MarkFisher: warning: temporary used to initialize a.

Comment: gosh I remember the time when Borland 4.5 was new. how ancient it makes me? sorry for the offtopic :-}

Comment: @meet apparently ancient compilers allowed to have a reference to a temporary variable. Borland, at least, gave a warning, while e.g. g++ didn't. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=986

Comment: Who cares what ancient rubbish compilers do?

Comment: @MarkFisher: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’
  int& a=10;

Comment: I used Borland C 2.0 in DOS for short time, then moved to 3.1 under Windows 3.1. It had good IDE and editor. But I have used references hardly ever. I think references are mostly for "pascal people". There are pointers which give all you need.

Comment: @Ashalynd: Did you mean ancient compilers create temporary variable in this case?

Comment: Turbo and Borland C++ are older than the first C++ standard so those non-standard things may not be surprised

Comment: @meet most probably so, otherwise this assignment would not be possible.

Comment: @Ashalynd: exactly.I was thinking same

Comment: Visual Studio still allows this.

Comment: @Ashalynd, that GCC bug report is a completely different case, that's binding a temporary to `const` reference, which is valid today in C++. This question is only about non-`const` references.

Comment: @SebastianRedl MSVC has many non-standard extensions. From Wakely's answer it's clear that it was allowed at one point. You can't violate the standard that doesn't exist. I can't reproduce though, what version are you using?

Comment: VS 2013, and VS 2015 still has this non-standard extension. However, apparently VS only allows it for class types. (Doesn't work with `int`, works with `struct S {};`.) There's a Level 4 warning issues when you do this.

Comment: Warning are logical errors in your code. Your code should compile with zero warnings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It used to be valid C++ to bind a reference to a temporary, so you could pass e.g. `double` to a function expecting `int&`, as explained in [The Design & Evolution of C++](http://stroustrup.com/dne.html) §3.7:

> I made one serious mistake, though, by allowing a non-`const` reference to be initialized by a non-lvalue. [...]
>   The reason to allow references to be initialized by non-lvalues was to allow the distinction between call-by-value and call-by-reference to be a detail specified by the called function and of no interest to the caller. For `const` references, this is possible, for non-`const` references it is not. For Release 2.0 the definition of C++ was changed to reflect this.

In C++ 2.0 (and in ISO C++) temporaries can only be bound to `const` references.